# Efficient way to convert Object arrays into collection in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

```js
const myObj = {
 a: [1, 2, 3],
 b: [2, 4, 6],
 c: [10, 20, 30]
}
```

Into

```js
const myCollection = [
  {a: 1, b: 2, c: 10},
  {a: 2, b: 4, c: 20},
  {a: 3, b: 6, c: 30}
]
```

I tried combinations of `Object.entries`, `Object.keys` and `map` but I'm always finding myself iterating twice or more over `myObj` and I'm not happy with any solution I came up with.
So what is the most efficient (in terms of time complexity) and elegant way that you can think to achieve that?

Comment: Please share the code you've tried. Also some details are needed, does your A,B and C always have the same length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reduce the entries and map nested arrays.

```js
const
    object = { a: [1, 2, 3], b: [2, 4, 6], c: [10, 20, 30] },
    result = Object
        .entries(object)
        .reduce((r, [k, a]) => a.map((v, i) => ({ ...r[i], [k]: v })), []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you'd need variable length:

```js
const myObj = {
  a: [1, 2, 3],
  b: [2, 4, 6,8, 10],
  c: [10, 20, 30, 40],
};

let myCollection = [];

Object.keys(myObj).forEach((k) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < myObj[k].length; i++) {
    if (!myCollection[i]) myCollection.push({});
    myCollection[i][k] = myObj[k][i];
  }
});
console.log(myCollection);
```

Answer (score 0):

That can be done using `Array.reduce`. I have attached the conversion code.

```js
const myObj = {
 a: [1, 2, 3],
 b: [2, 4, 6],
 c: [10, 20, 30]
}

const myCollection = [
  {a: 1, b: 2, c: 10},
  {a: 2, b: 4, c: 20},
  {a: 3, b: 6, c: 30}
]

const maxLength = Math.max(...Object.values(myObj).map(item => item.length));

const myObjKeys = Object.keys(myObj);
const result = [ ...Array(maxLength).keys() ].map((index) => {
  return myObjKeys.reduce((acc, curKey) => {
    if (myObj[curKey].length > index) {
      acc[curKey] = myObj[curKey][index];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ramdajs`, I could suggest you a short way like below

```js
const myObj = {
  a: [1, 2, 3],
  b: [2, 4, 6],
  c: [10, 20, 30]
}

const res = R.map(
  R.zipObj(R.keys(myObj)),
  R.values(myObj)
)

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

In [ramdajs homepage, criteria 3 in *What's Different*](https://ramdajs.com/), it cited that

> The parameters to Ramda functions are arranged to make it convenient for currying. The data to be operated on is generally supplied last.

Comment: Thumbs up for elegancy, but I'm not using Ramda. But it did gave me a direction of how to achieve the same with Lodash (almost the same functions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` on `Object.values` and then use `reduce()` on each value.

```js
const myObj = {
 a: [1, 2, 3],
 b: [2, 4, 6],
 c: [10, 20, 30]
}

let keys = Object.keys(myObj);
const arr = Object.values(myObj).map((a) => a.reduce((ac, a, i) => ({...ac, [keys[i]]:a}), {}));
console.log(arr)
```