# Converting object to array format with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-conversion

I have a data object like this:

```
{
  "backgroundColor": [
    "#E5700F",
    "#DA830F",
  ],
  "data": [
    26,
    10,
  ],
}
```

I want to change the format to be like this:

```
[
{
"backgroundColor": "#E5700F",
"data": 26,},
{
"backgroundColor": "#DA830F",
"data": 10,},
]
```

how to achieve it using javascript?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/64135972/2729605 can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
const old = {
  backgroundColor: ["#E5700F", "#DA830F"],
  data: [26, 10],
};

let newArray = [];

old.backgroundColor.forEach((item, idx) => {
  newArray.push({ backgroundColor: item, data: old.data[idx] });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work if the object is not dynamic.

```js
let data = {
  "backgroundColor": [
    "#E5700F",
    "#DA830F",
  ],
  "data": [
    26,
    10,
  ],
};

let result = data.backgroundColor.map(function(item, index) {
  return {
    backgroundColor: item,
    data: data.data[index]
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:
Note that the array's length may not be equal, so it is best to consider this in your data conversion routine.

```js
let sourceData = {
    "backgroundColor": [
        "#E5700F",
        "#DA830F",
    ],
    "data": [
        26,
        10,
    ],
};

let result = [];
let length = Math.max(sourceData.backgroundColor.length, sourceData.data.length);

for (let index = 0; index < length; index++) {
    result.push({
        "backgroundColor": sourceData.backgroundColor[index],
        "data": sourceData.data[index]
    })
}

console.log(result);
```